# Can you devise a simple macro to effectively produce a compiler error when used?

Tags: c, macros, language-lawyer

I am looking for a strange macro definition, on purpose: I need a macro defined in such a way, that in the event the macro is effectively used in compiled code, the compiler will unfailingly produce an error.

The background: Since C11 had introduced several new keywords, and a new C++11 standard also added a few, I would like to introduce a header file in my projects (mostly using C89/C95 compilers with a few additions) to force developers to refrain from using these new keywords as identifier names, unless, of course, they are recognized as keywords in the intended fashion.

In the ancient past, I did this for `new` like this:

```c
#define new *** /* C++ keyword, do not use */
```

And yes, it worked. Until it didn't, when a programmer forgot the underscore in a parameter name:

```c
void myfunction(uint16_t new parameter);
```

I used variants since, but I've never been challenged again.

Now I intend to create a file with all keywords not supported by various compilers, and I'm looking for a dependable solution, at best with a not too confusing error message. "Syntax error" would be OK, but "parameter missing" would be confusing already.
I'm thinking along the lines of

```c
#define atomic +*=*+ /* C11 derived keyword; do not use */
```

and aside from my usual hesitation, I'm quite sure that any use (but not the definition) of the macro will produce an error.

EDIT: To make it even more difficult, MISRA will only allow the use of the basic source and execution character set, so `@` or `$` are not allowed.

But I'd like to ask the community: Do you have a better macro value? As effective, but shorter? Or even longer but more dependable in some strange situation? Or a completely different method to generate an error (only using the compiler, please, not external tools!) when a "discouraged" identifier is used for any purpose?

Disclaimer:
And, yes, I know I can use a grep or a parser to run on a nightly build, and report the warnings it finds. But dropping an immediate error on the developers desk is quicker, and certain to be fixed before checking in.

Comment: I knew someone who used to use Koala eyes: something like `{-([]) * ([])-}` …

Comment: Personally, I intentionally use c++ reserved words as identifiers to avoid people using c++ compilers on it. `this` is my favourite, but `new` and `delete` are fine, too.

Comment: @wildplasser I will never do that for customer projects, in case they want/need to migrate their project to another compiler, or even port the software to using C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the sport is for the shortest tokensequence that always produces an error, any combination of two 1 character operators that can't legally occur together, but

- don't use `({` or `})` because gcc has a special meaning for that
- don't use any sort of unbalanced parentheses because they can lead you far away until the error is recognized
- don't use `<` or `>` because they could match template parameters for C++
- don't use prefix operators as second character
- don't use postfix operators as first character

This leave some possibilities

- `..`, `.|` and other combinations with `.` since `.` expects a following identifier
- `&|`, `&/`, `&^`, `&,`, `&;`
- `!|`, `!/`, `!^`, `!,`, `!;`

But actually to be more user friendly I'd also first place a `_Pragma` in it so the compiler would also spit a warning.

```
#define atomic _Pragma("message \"some instructive text that you should read\"") ..
```

Comment: +1 The idea with `_Pragma` is really good. But for me the 'sport' is more to have it _reliably_ produce an error, even if the program or source file is not conforming or even malformed. Shorter is better, but reliability is more important.

Comment: I removed `!=`, since a (malformed) source file might even compile correctly using it.

Comment: @Johan, right, I completely overlooked that that is an operator :) I also added some more syntax to the `_Pragma`. This one is gcc specific, but other compilers that don't implement it that way should complain anyhow.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can just use an illegal symbol:

```
#define bad_name @
```

---

Another one that would work would be this:

```
static const char *illegal_keyword = "";

#define bad_name (illegal_keyword = "bad_name")
```

It would error you that you are changing a constant. Also, the error message will usually be quite good:

```
Line 8: error: called object 'illegal_keyword = "printf"' is not a function
```

---

And the final one that is perhaps the shortest and will always work is this:

```
#define bad_name #
```

Because the preprocessor will never replace twice, and `#` is illegal outside of the prepocessor this will always error.

Comment: $ like @ is not in the base character set. Sorry, I forgot to mention. Will edit.

Comment: @Johan Bezem: what do you mean? $ is in ASCII, IIRC. Could you perhaps post which encoding your files use?

Comment: ISO Std 9899:2011 5.2.1 p. 22 "Character sets"

Comment: @Johan Bezem: you can always use `#`, it is a legal C character, but not outside of the preprocessor. It gives you a hard time debugging what's wrong though :D http://codepad.org/ZPnZtSf4

Answer (score 2):

```
#define atomic do not use atomic
```

The expansion is not recursive so it stops.  The only way to stop it from being a compilation error is:

```
#define do
#define not
#define use
```

but that's verboten because `do` and `not` are keywords.

The error message might even include 'atomic'.  You can increase the probability of that by rephrasing the message:

```
#define atomic atomic cannot be used
```

(Now you are not playing with keywords in the message, though.)

Comment: `not` is an alternative spelling (iso646.h), not a keyword. You need to `#include <iso646.h>` for it to be defined.

Comment: @JohanBezem: yes, in C you're correct.  In C++, `not` is a full keyword, though.

Answer (score 1):

I think `[[]]` isn't a valid sequence of tokens anywhere, so you could use that:

```
#define keyword [[]]
```

The error will be a syntax error, complaining about `[` or `]`.

Comment: Might give some meaning to that and change it to `[[illegal_keyword]]`.

Comment: @nightcracker: That illegal_keyword probably won't show up in the error message, so it doesn't really help.

Answer (score 1):

My attempt:

```
#define new new[-1]
#define atomic atomic[-1]
```