# #defining something as #error

Tags: visual-studio, macros, c-preprocessor

In the process of getting rid of old macros in our code, I need to define the old macro as an error with a meaningful compiler message.

E.g., old code:

```
#define DIVIDE_BY_TWO(x) x/2
```

In the new code, to prevent the usage of this macro I'd like to write:

```
#define DIVIDE_BY_TWO(x) #error DIVIDE_BY_TWO is obsolete, use DIV_2 instead
```

But when I compile the above line I get:

```
error C2162: expected macro formal parameter
```

What is the correct way to do it?

Comment: Try replacing the (x) with( ...)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you devise a simple macro to effectively produce a compiler error when used?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9006358/can-you-devise-a-simple-macro-to-effectively-produce-a-compiler-error-when-used)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A macro can't have directives or change the preprocessor state. You could leave `DIVIDE_BY_TWO` undefined, but then it doesn't help to find the replacement macro. The only way to do it portably is to define it as something like this:

```
#define DIVIDE_BY_TWO error_DIVIDE_BY_TWO_is_obsolete_use_DIV_2_instead
```

Which should give an error that `error_DIVIDE_BY_TWO_is_obsolete_use_DIV_2_instead` is not defined and hopefully that will give enough hints has to how to replace it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with using `#error` is that creates an error at the time that part of the code is analyzed by the preprocessor.  You want to create an error when the macro is expanded.  You can't, unfortunately, use `#error` for that.

I don't believe there is a way to generate a clear human-readable error message reliably in portable C.  (You can, of course, make the macro expand to something that's syntactically invalid, though, which will at least stop compilation.)  gcc supports doing it with `_Pragma`.  Your question is effectively equivalent to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9006358/can-you-devise-a-simple-macro-to-effectively-produce-a-compiler-error-when-used) and the answer there explains how to use `_Pragma` as well as other options for creating a fatal error.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a preprocessor directive in `#define` since what you're asking for is to run the preprocessor twice.

If a line begins with an `#` it is a directive to the preprocessor and would be interpreted. If it doesn't, then it is subjected to macro substituion and replacement if such a macro exists.

The best you could do is to define the deprecated macro as some expression that would return an error for sure.